# How do I set an element in a container to scroll as a fixed element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I formatted a single webpage into three sections using HTML Section Tags. I created two divs in section one: a parent and a child. I did not create any divs in section two or three. The parent contains a hidden rectangle element nested in the center of the parent container which itself is centered in the middle of section one. Each of the three sections render as full screens.

When a user scrolls through the first section, the rectangle reveals itself. Once the user scrolls to the middle of section two, the rectangle scales 4 times its original size (or enlarges) and fills section two.

The problem is, I used CSS, “position: fixed” to center the hidden rectangle element in section one, but I cannot get the rectangle, after it has scaled up in section two, to scroll up and away with section two as the user scrolls to section three. The rectangle seems fixed to the viewport not the section two container. I want it fixed to the section two container not the viewport. I tried “position: sticky” and “position: relative” to tie the rectangle element to its container so it scrolls away with section two, but for some reason, it stops the scaling feature of my rectangle element in section two. Please help!

```js
myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 1) {
    myID.className = "child show"
  } else {
    myID.className = "child hide"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);

myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 729) {
    myID.className = "child scale"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.three {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  width: 274px;
  height: 154px;
  position: fixed;
  background: plum;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.scale {
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<section class="one">
  <div class="parent">
    <div id="myID" class="child hide scale"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="two">
</section>
<section class="three">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Move the parent DIV outside the first section so it could be over the first two sections.
- Use `position:sticky` for the child DIV
- Switch CSS classes of the child on the `scroll` event

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const child = document.querySelector('.child');
  child.classList.toggle('visible', window.scrollY > 0);
  child.classList.toggle('expanded', window.scrollY > window.innerHeight * 0.7);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.three {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.child.expanded {
  top: 100vh;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.child .content{
  position: absolute;
  inset: 30px;
  background: plum;
}

.child {
  transform: scale(.25);
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;
}
.child.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div id="myID" class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<section class="one">
</section>
<section class="two">
</section>
<section class="three">
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for the code! It works beautifully! However, can you show me how to change the inner window expansion of the child div so it is not the full page size when it scales up. I think I want to make it smaller than the full screen so I can have a border around it.

Comment: O sorry I forgot. Your up vote wish is granted!

Comment: @Megan added another div inside `.child`, set `inset` to your needed value

Comment: do I add anything inside the div that is inside the child?

Comment: @Megan yes ....

Comment: I don't mean to be a bother but it did not make the child smaller/ have border around it. I added a div inside .child and called the class kid in the HTML. Then in the CSS I wrote .kid{inset:30px;}. The child still fills the whole screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Megan will solve tomorrow

Comment: I appreciate your time and help, thank you.

Comment: @Megan have you seen the updated code? place your HTML into `#myID.content`. pls try

Comment: Hats off to you it worked!